# find min value in nested FormArray

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular projet, one of my form has the following structure:

```
this.serviceForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  [...],
  options: this.formBuilder.array([
    this.formBuilder.group({
      [...],
      availabilities: this.formBuilder.array([
        this.formBuilder.group({
          [...],
          price: ['', Validators.required]
        })
      ])
    })
  ])
});
```

I want to find the minimum price in my form.
I tried this but I am sure there is a better way to do :

```
getMinPrice(serviceForm: FormGroup) {
  let min = serviceForm.value.options[0].availabilities[0].price;

  serviceForm.value.options.forEach(i => {
    i.availabilities.forEach(j => {
      if (j.price < min) {
        min = j.price;
      }
    });
  });

  return min;
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you **do not care about the context of the min. price**, you could simply collect the price values across the nested objects and then perform the min. search by using `Math.min`.

Try with the following:

```
interface FormValue {
  options: Option[];
}

interface Option {
  availabilities: Availability[];
}

interface Availability {
  price: number;
}

function minPrice(f: FormValue) {
  const prices: number[] = f.options.map(option => option.availabilities)
                 .reduce((acc, curr)=> acc.concat(curr), [] as Availability[])
                 .map(availability => availability.price)
                 .reduce((acc, curr) => acc.concat(curr), [] as number[]);
  return Math.min(...prices);
}
```

**Sidenote:** the interfaces are ofc incomplete, I defined them in order to have type-inference in an editor.

Comment: What do you mean by caring about the context of the min price?

Comment: for example, which `Availability` object has that price

Answer (score -1):

You can use `apply` to run the standard `Math` methods against an array:

```
const values = [3, 5, 6, 2, 45, 6, 32];

const min = Math.min.apply(null, values);
const max = Math.max.apply(null, values);

console.log(min, max);
```

So you can just select out your `j.price` values and run them through that mechanism.

Comment: passing a null feels kinda odd, specially considering that `Math.min` can take a params argument

Comment: @Jota.Toledo - You know `Math.min(...prices)` transpiles to `Math.min.apply(Math, prices);`? Does is still feel kinda odd?